# SignalR $.connection is undefined - MVC 5 Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I saw an earlier forum post regarding this topic and the author prefaced his post with "I admit it, I don't know what I'm doing."  I fall in that same category.

I found a great MVC SignalR progress bar example at https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1124691/SignalR-Progress-Bar-Simple-Example-Sending-Live-D but it was written a few years ago using jQuery 1.10.x and SignalR v2.2.1.  My application (ASP.NET MVC) is MVC5, using jQuery 3.3.1 and SignalR v2.4.1.

When the page loads, and the inline function gets to:
`var progress = $.connection.progressHub`
I'm getting a

> "Cannot read property 'progressHub' of undefined"

error.  If I break this line down and try to assign the value of $.connection to a variable, the result is that $.connection is not defined.  I've read through many posts, and several point to jQuery being loaded twice.  From what I can see in Chrome's debugger, that doesn't appear to be the case, as shown here:
[image: Progress Bar Debug console]

I'm at a loss as to what is happening here.  I think I have all the pieces in place, but clearly something is missing.  I'm hoping it is something simple that I've missed, but any suggestions are welcome.  I've included quite a bit of information below, to help troubleshoot this.  Thanks in advance for any help on this!

The _Layout.cshtml file includes the following (I'm using DevExpress components, but I'm going to assume that is not the problem):

```
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Html.DevExpress().GetStyleSheets(
            new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.NavigationAndLayout },
            new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.GridView }
        )


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Helper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>

    @Html.DevExpress().GetScripts(
        new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.NavigationAndLayout },
        new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.GridView }
    )
```

and

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
            var progress = $.connection.progressHub;
            console.log(progress);

            // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
            progress.client.AddProgress = function (message, percentage) {
                ProgressBarModal("show", message + " " + percentage);
                $('#ProgressMessage').width(percentage);
                if (percentage == "100%") {
                    ProgressBarModal();
                }
            };

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                var connectionId = $.connection.hub.id;
                console.log(connectionId);
            });

        });
    </script>
```

The layout also has a Bootstrap modal div that is displayed when the user clicks a button on the view that starts the process.

The project has a /Hubs folder with a class for ProgressHub as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace NOCPortal
{
    public class ProgressHub : Hub
    {
        public string msg = "Initializing and Preparing...";
        public int count = 1;
        public static void SendMessage(string msg, int count)
        {
            var message = "Process completed for " + msg;
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
            hubContext.Clients.All.sendMessage(string.Format(message), count);
        }
        public void GetCountAndMessage()
        {
            Clients.Caller.sendMessage(string.Format(msg), count);
        }
    }
}
```

The "Helper.js" script contains a function which the progress bar...

```
function ProgressBarModal(showHide) {

    if (showHide === 'show') {
        $('#mod-progress').modal('show');
        if (arguments.length >= 2) {
            $('#progressBarParagraph').text(arguments[1]);
        } else {
            $('#progressBarParagraph').text('Missing Description');
        }

        window.progressBarActive = true;

    } else {
        $('#mod-progress').modal('hide');
        window.progressBarActive = false;
    }
}
```

The view is very simple:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test2";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Test2</h2>

@ViewBag.Message
<br />
<button onclick="StartProcess()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-success">Start the process</button>
<script>
        //CALLING METHOD IN THE CONTROLLER TO DO SOME WORK
        function StartProcess() {

            $.getJSON("/Home/ProgressTest",
                {},
                function (data) {
                    if (!data) {
                        alert("Success");
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
        }

</script>
```

The BundleConfig.cs file is the default that was generated:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace NOCPortal
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks again for reading through this, and for any assistance!

Comment: did you add MapSignarR() in your Startup.cs?

Comment: Had the same error as you awhile back below is what fixed mine hope it helps if not I can take a deeper look tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        //line below always gets me with SignalR don't know if this is your problem
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers on this.  I did have have the mapping in place in Startup.cs, but that didn't affect the issue.  It turns out that it WAS an incompatibility between SignalR and the DevExpress components.  Those components typically require registering 3rd party controls in the Web.config file.  However, that method breaks SignalR and some other third party controls.  Removing the automatic registration from web.config resolved the issue and allowed the progressHub to work normally, along with the rest of the SignalR functionality.